# Increase my Ubuntu performance without swap partition

Tags: system-installation, ram, swap, disk-usage

I ever install Ubuntu without swap partition or file. Is that OK or must I create one?

Comment: See: [Do we still need swap partitions on desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291378/do-we-still-need-swap-partitions-on-desktop), [Do I need a swap partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/398258/do-i-need-a-swap-partition), [Linux: don't create swap partition?](http://superuser.com/questions/639618/linux-dont-create-swap-partition)

Answer (score 1):

Swap partition is needed for the system itself and some apps go crazy if there is no swap partition, and it is used for hibernation too. So I think it would worth that amount of space it needs.

Comment: Not true. I've been running the linux desktop for years with a swap. When apps go crazy and eat all the memory, then the OOM comes along and kills them and that's the end of that. It's not a big deal anymore.

Comment: @SurpriseDog I absolutely agree. I used to have problems with not having swap, but nowadays it is not that necessary anymore. Although it is still a good thing to have a swap partition to make the kernel be able to actually swap some pages that are unlikely to be needed soon, so this memory can be used for caching.

Answer (score 0):

The Swap partition is necessary. However, IF the PC that has been installed
on has large amounts of RAM, the swap partition may be used less. System itself will deal with RAM/swap usage. Should be no real need to tinker.
With small RAM amounts, swap partition is crucial! In this situation, swap is needed so that the system has a 'place to go' once the RAM is filled up.
Remember that swap is going to behave as if it is RAM, meaning random access.
That means data is constantly in/out of RAM/swap while applications and the 
OS itself runs. Hope this helps Craig