# Do I Really Need A Swap Partition?

Tags: swap

I am about to format and manually partition my hard drive for Ubuntu for the first time. I have 16GB of RAM. I am wondering if I should even allocate a swap partition? Should I just make a root partition and a home partition?

Comment: Duplicates http://askubuntu.com/questions/291378/do-we-still-need-swap-partitions-on-desktop http://askubuntu.com/questions/398258/do-i-need-a-swap-partition

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you can just make a root partition and you would be fine. But if you hibernate your computer, you will need the swap space. Also if you do not have a lot of ram, it will be useful to have swap space.

Read this:

https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space

Comment: I currently have the default install and it made 3 partitions. One Fat32 (512MB), 200 gig ex4 for /, and 16gig for swap space. It says that the small 512MB partition is a mount point of /boot/eft, and the flag is boot. Do I need one of those too?

Comment: What is the fat32 for?

Comment: Dno, it's just there when I clicked to install Ubuntu